# Login Authentication using stored procedure in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, authentication, stored-procedures, navicat

I want to create a login authentication in Laravel using the stored procedure that has been prepared. When the user inputs the correct username and password, they will be redirected to the home page. However when I try it it stays on the login page. Help me to correct my program code

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `9_USER_LOGIN`(
    IN p_username VARCHAR(50),
    IN p_password VARCHAR(50),
    OUT p_is_valid INT
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_count INT;

    -- Check if the username and password combination exists
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count
    FROM 9_user
    WHERE USERNAME = p_username AND `PASSWORD` = p_password;

    -- Set the output parameter based on the result
    IF v_count > 0 THEN
        SET p_is_valid = 1; -- Valid authentication
    ELSE
        SET p_is_valid = 0; -- Invalid authentication
    END IF;
END
```

LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $username = $request->input('username');
        $password = $request->input('password');

        // Call the stored procedure using DB facade
        $result = DB::select('CALL 9_USER_LOGIN(?, ?, @is_valid)', [$username, $password]);

        // Retrieve the output parameter
        $isValid = DB::selectOne('SELECT @is_valid AS is_valid')->is_valid;

        if ($isValid) {
            // Authentication successful
            return redirect()->route('home');
        } else {
            // Invalid credentials
            return back()->with('error', 'Invalid username or password');
        }
    }
}
```

login.blade.php

```
 <form action="{{ route('login') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-8">
            <div class="icheck-primary">
              <input type="checkbox" id="remember">
              <label for="remember">
                Ingat Saya
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->         
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button> 
          <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: Or [Breeze](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze). Also storing passwords in plain text is quite a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using DB::select to call the stored procedure, it expects a result set, but the stored procedure is only using output parameters.

So in your stored procedure after the `END IF;` return 1

```
SELECT 1 AS dummy;
```

This dummy result set will allow Laravel's `DB::select` to work correctly.